# Genism object to a readable result

Tags: python, nlp

I have checked the other two answers to similar question but in vain.

```
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
from gensim.models.tfidfmodel import TfidfModel
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

article = "Aziz Ismail Ansari[1] (/ənˈsɑːri/; born February 23, 1983) is an American actor, writer, producer, director, and comedian. He is known for his role as Tom Haverford on the NBC series Parks and Recreation (2009–2015) and as creator and star of the Netflix series Master of None (2015–) for which he won several acting and writing awards, including two Emmys and a Golden Globe, which was the first award received by an Asian American actor for acting on television.[2][3][4]Ansari began performing comedy in New York City while a student at New York University in 2000. He later co-created and starred in the MTV sketch comedy show Human Giant, after which he had acting roles in a number of feature films.As a stand-up comedian, Ansari released his first comedy special, Intimate Moments for a Sensual Evening, in January 2010 on Comedy Central Records. He continues to perform stand-up on tour and on Netflix. His first book, Modern Romance: An Investigation, was released in June 2015. He was included in the Time 100 list of most influential people in 2016.[5] In July 2019, Ansari released his fifth comedy special Aziz Ansari: Right Now, which was nominated for a Grammy Award for Best Comedy Album.[6]"

tokens = regexp_tokenize(article, "\w+|\d+")
az_only_alpha = [t for t in tokens if t.isalpha()]
#below line will take some time to execute.
az_no_stop_words = [t for t in az_only_alpha if t not in stopwords.words('english')]
az_lemmetize = [wordnetLem.lemmatize(t) for t in az_no_stop_words]

dictionary = Dictionary([az_lemmetize])

x = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in [az_lemmetize]]
cp = TfidfModel(x)
cp[x[0]]
```

**The last line gives me an empty array whereas I expect a list of tupples with id and their weights.**

Comment: Have you tried adding another document ?

Comment: @ygorg No! I have just tried my hand on a string and finally will try to deduce what topic the string is talking about.

Comment: TfIdf computes the importance of words in a document according to other documents. With only one document every word will have the same score. If you only have one document the frequency of words might be more suited to your problem.

Comment: Ahh!! That is it! Thanks @ygorg. basic mistake on my part